# Search elements inside string

Tags: php, string, split

Let me explain what I want to do.

I need to connect to a device using SSH and execute some shell commands. I get the result of these commands (stream, using `ssh2_fetch_stream`) and save into a variable. This Works fine.

But what I need to know is how can I search by elements in a string?
Here a sample string:

```
$stringToSearch = "id=10 name=interfacename1 stringx=102040 stringy=50606040,id=20 name=interfacename2 stringx=872345 stringy=23875454,id=30 name=interfacename3 stringx=654389 stringy=34567865";
```

I need to obtain all the 'name=' results, like (`SELECT name FROM stringToSearch;`) and this would return:

```
____name____   
interfacename1  
interfacename2  
interfacename3
```

I created a simple function to read this string.

```
<?php
   function readString($stringToSearch, $start, $end) {
   $result = '-1';
   // I need to do a loop here, but how can I do it to read and return all elements between $start and $end? 
   if(strlen(strstr($stringToSearch, $start)) > 0)
   {
        $startsAt = strpos($stringToSearch, $start) + strlen($start);
        $endsAt = strpos($stringToSearch, $end, $startsAt);
        $result = substr($stringToSearch, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
   }
   return $result;
}     
$stringToSearch = 'id=10 name=interfacename1 stringx=102040 stringy=50606040,id=20 name=interfacename2 stringx=872345 stringy=23875454,id=30 name=interfacename3 stringx=654389 stringy=34567865';
$element = readString($stringToSearch, 'name=', ' '); // Will return only the 1st element
?>
```

But I can only retrieve the 1st element. How can I get all the elements in this string?

Comment: Maybe it's better to explode string by space/comma, and then explode exploded stings by `=` and find keys what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this solution :)

```
<?php
$stringToSearch = "id=10 name=interfacename1 stringx=102040 stringy=50606040,id=20 name=interfacename2 stringx=872345 stringy=23875454,id=30 name=interfacename3 stringx=654389 stringy=34567865";

var_dump(getName($stringToSearch));
function getName($stringToSearch) {
    $pattern = '/name=([A-Z0-9]*)/i';
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $stringToSearch, $result) == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    return $result[1];
}
```

**Enhancement** (to get all values of desired parameter):

```
/**
  * @param String $varName : the name of variable to get their values. ex: stringx, stringy
  * @param String $stringToSearch : the string to search in
  * @return Array if variable was found in $stringToSearch, NULL else
  */
function getName($varName, $stringToSearch) {
    $pattern = '/' . $varName . '=([A-Z0-9]*)/i';
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $stringToSearch, $result) == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    return $result[1];
}
```

Comment: Just another question: Is there a way to do a similar search, but usign something like this: SELECT stringx WHERE name=interface1?

Comment: In this case you need a ETL tool: Extract Transform Load, like Talend, to store in a database the transfromation that you can made on this type of string. see this link for more information : http://www.talend.com/resource/free-etl.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Halayem Anis's answer I was able to find all the elements in the string.
But I found other problem. If I have a string like that: name="foo bar" (with space at the middle).

To solve this problem I adapted the $pattern.

The result is:

```
//$varname = string to be searched like name=
//$stringToSearch = the original string
function getName($varName, $stringToSearch) {
    $pattern = '/(?<=' . $varName . ')"(.*?)"/i';  // Changed this to get all between name="" 
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $stringToSearch, $result) == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    return $result[1];
}
```