# How to search text using php if ($text contains “Prépresse”)

Tags: php, strstr

i Have the string contains this word Prépresse but i do that it's not working :

```
if(strstr($text,'Prépresse')){

echo'OK';}
```

but not working because i have the accent é how can i resolve that

i called my function but not worked for me i need get the strings between two paramètres so my function:

```
public function get_string_between($string,$start,$end){

        $string ="".$string;
        $ini=strpos($string,$start);
        if($ini==0)return false;
        $ini+=strlen($start);
        $len=strpos($string,$end,$ini)-$ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);


    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `strpos` for this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php - Might be better as it seems you have Unicode characters in your phrase

Comment: Might be your `error_reporting` is not `on` else you'll get an error within your `if` condition missing closing `)` `paranthesis` over `if(strstr($text,'Prépresse')` `<----------------here` should be `if(strstr($text,'Prépresse'))` instead

Comment: See if this will serve to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949029/search-elements-inside-string/27984567#27984567

Comment: people asking question, getting answer but not interested in marking an answer. WTF IS GOING ON? I a deleting y answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

```
$text = "Prépresse abcd test";

if (strpos($text,'Prépresse') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

**output**:-

```
true
```

Comment: @ Ravi Hirani ,so i used that but not working for me $data ['format'] =trim($formatstring->get_string_between ( $str, "Format               ", "Prépresse" ));